# in-place sorting algorithm for integer array

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have an array of integers and its size . I am looking for a sorting algorithm which is in-place ( We can't use a secondary array or variable (except counters) ).
Its time complexity should be O(n).(Is it possible?)
I want to write a c++ code for this algorithm and here is what I've written. But I know its time complexity isn't good. 
Can anybody help me?

```
    void sort(int a[], int n)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n-1 ; i++)
        {
          for( int j=i+1; j<n ; j++)
          {
            if(a[i]<a[j])
            {
               a[j]=a[i]+a[j];
               a[i]=a[j]-a[i];
               a[j]=a[j]-a[i];
             }
           }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for an unbounded input range, all known comparison based sorting algorithm can only achieve *0(n)* if the input array was already sorted.

Comment: Counting sort could help if you know the range of integers

Comment: thats a strange way to swap two values. If you are that strict about not having any additional temporary variable, also using `i` and `j` shouldnt be allowed. I mean, simply do `temp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = temp;` why so much more complicated and unreadable than necessary ?

Comment: Sorting in linear time is possible but not in general case. It requires that input satisfy special conditions. Look at radix sort or counting sort at Wikipedia.

Comment: [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) is kinda sorta `O(n)` (it's `O(n*log R)` where `R` is the range of values in the input; but many tend to hand-wave away the log factor).

Comment: @Igor: if you know the values fit into an `int`, then `log R` is O(1); no handwaving is required (since it was part of the problem specification).

Comment: @rici That's precisely the hand-waving I was talking about. If you posit finite memory whose addresses can all fit into, say, 32 bits, then `n` cannot grow to infinity and all algorithms are `O(1)` (albeit with possibly a very large constant factor). A random-access architecture must be modeled as having word size `w` proportional to `log n` - it just doesn't make sense to perform asymptotic analysis with a model that has constant word size. Now, once you have a machine with a large enough word to address any of `n` elements, each of those elements can itself be as large as `n`.

Comment: @tobi303 Better still, `std::swap(a[i], [a[j]);`

Comment: Unless you have very ***specific*** requirements on the sorting, always use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). For the majority of use-cases it will be better than anything you can come up with.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik sure, I would even recommend to use `std::sort`. Actually I have no idea if that is really in-place, but the interface is kind of in-place, and thats all that counts for me (unless I really aim to design my own sorting, but thats different story than finding a solution for sorting an array of integers)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I was going to address that issue, actually. Suppose you take the view that the word size is unlimited, rather than fixed. Now the input size needs to be counted in bits, not fixed-size words (because the words are no longer fixed-size). Once you do that, the algorithm is still O(n) because the `n` is now a bit-count and the algorithm is linear in the bitsize of the values. Of course, you are free to regard that as handwaving, too, but I don't think it leaves any ends untied.

Comment: @Igor, or to put it another way, in order to assert that the algorithm is O(n log n), you need to replace the fiction that the datum can be *stored* in a fixed-size word with the fiction that the datum can be *expressed* as a fixed-size word. If you eliminate both fictions, you get back to the starting place.

Comment: @rici Hmm, I think you are right. I see what you are saying. If you have input that's `n` bits large, then you can either assume that the range of values is bounded and you have `O(n)` elements of fixed bit size, which you can radix-sort in `O(n)` time; or you can assume that you have `k=n/log n` elements each `w=log n` bits large (as large as the machine word can represent), which you can radix-sort in `O(k*w) = O(n)` time.

Comment: Merge sort and radix sort normally need a secondary array. An optimized quick sort uses O(log(n)) stack space. Heap sort is O(1) space with time complexity O(n log(n)).